# Center an equation, inside align environment of amsmath, like using gather

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, alignment

In the example given below, I would like the first and third equations to be aligned at the = sign, while the second equation should be centered, like in the gather environment. Using gathered inside align environment doesn't help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}    % for \because

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \nabla \times[\nabla \times A]_{\varphi} &=\frac{-4 \pi G \rho}{c^2} \\
    \begin{gathered}
        \because \quad \nabla \times v=\left[\frac{1}{s} \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial \phi}-\frac{\partial v_\phi}{\partial z}\right]
    \end{gathered} \\
    \nabla \times A &=\frac{\partial A_\phi}{\partial z} \hat{R}+\frac{1}{R}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial R}\left(R A_\phi\right)\right] \hat{z}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second equation shown here is not its actual long form. And it actually defines a general relation. I need it centered, since if u try to align it at = sign, it would mess up everything. I have tried using intertext, but doesn't it produce more vertical space, then the space between two lines of equations in align environment?

Comment: It looks weird because i have cut down the second equation to two terms, when in reality, it takes up the whole line. So, it makes more sense to center it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can center the second equation with respect to `&` of the `align` environment with `\mathclap` from the [mathtools](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package. `\mathclap` puts its argument to in a zero width box and centers it.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}    % for \because
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for \mathclap

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \nabla \times[\nabla \times A]_{\varphi} & =\frac{-4 \pi G \rho}{c^2} \\
    & \mathclap{\because \quad \nabla \times v=\left[\frac{1}{s} \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial \phi}-\frac{\partial v_\phi}{\partial z}\right]}\\
    \nabla \times A                          & =\frac{\partial A_\phi}{\partial z} \hat{R}+\frac{1}{R}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial R}\left(R A_\phi\right)\right] \hat{z}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: second equation centered]

Anyway, as said by David Carlisle, the simplest and the clearest is to align all equal signs.

```tex
\begin{align}
    \nabla \times[\nabla \times A]_{\varphi} & =\frac{-4 \pi G \rho}{c^2}                                                      \\
    \because \quad \nabla \times v           &=\left[\frac{1}{s} \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial \phi}-\frac{\partial v_\phi}{\partial z}\right] \\
    \nabla \times A                          & =\frac{\partial A_\phi}{\partial z} \hat{R}+\frac{1}{R}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial R}\left(R A_\phi\right)\right] \hat{z}
\end{align}
```

[image: all with align]

Comment: That worked like a charm. You sir, are a genius.